# Cinnamon doesn't load at launch loading LXDE instead, what is wrong here?

Tags: linux, desktop-environment, cinnamon

Hi I Found myself with this weird issue that after installing Cinnamon desktop environment on a Debian-based linux distro, with `apt-get upgrade` `apt-get install cinnamon`, at the log-in moment even selecting cinammon or cinammon 2D the PC ends loading LXDE (wich was the first desktop-enviroment that I have installed).

Logging in as any user I have the same problem, even as root. Tried solving the problem in a "windows like style" (I am pretty new to linux) removing the software with `apt-get purge cinnamon` `apt-get clean` and then re-doing the same thing updating and reinstalling with `apt-get upgrade` `apt-get install cinnamon`, however this did't work for me.

The only thing that I think that may be causing the problem is the distro I am using is just a distro created at my university and I think that may not have enough maintennance or also I know that the packages that I installed from cinnamon come from a repository in my university so maybe there are not the same packages that everybody else uses. anyways I am just guessing, I don't know exactly how the repositories works, so any advice, or idea is welcome thanks.

Comment: "apt-get purge" actually uninstalled cinnamon and you don't mention that you reinstalled it. Is it currently installed?

Comment: yes I did, after `apt-get purge` used again `apt-get upgrade` `apt-get install cinnamon`, Cinammon and cinammon 2d can be selected In the log-in menu